# Query builder mongodb index datetime

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, full-text-search

I'm looking to execute custome query with doctrine odm in fulltext search and datetime range

Indexes are already generated on mongodb

Here is my code :

```
$search = $dm->createQueryBuilder('VideoBundle:Video');

        if (isset($_POST['date']))
        {
            $from = new \DateTime($_POST['date']);
            $to = new \DateTime('today');

            $search->field('published')->range($from, $to);
        }

        $search->expr()->operator('$text', array(
            '$search'   => $_POST['searchvideo'],
        ));

        $search->limit(50);

        $query = $search->getQuery();

        $search = $query->execute();
```

Query returned and executed by Doctrine Mongodb in Symfony profiler is :

```
db.Video.find().limit(50);
```

Any help?

Comment: You can use,  ->gte($form),->lte($to) it may help you.